# Ошибка синтаксиса MySQL?

Tags: phpmyadmin, база-данных, php, mysql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO league(user,email,password,rival,key) 
                    VALUES ('$this->user','$this->email','$this->pass','0','0')";
```

ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'key) 
>                   VALUES ('user1','user1@gmail.com','usrpsw','0','0')'
> at line 1

поле key int(11) NULL(no) DEFAULT 0

Comment: поле key int(11), а записываете строку

Comment: убрал кавычки: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES ('user1','user1@gmail.com','usrpsw','0',0)' at line 1

Comment: имеется ввиду, что key должен быть числом

Comment: вот я и вставил 0 без кавычек, т.е. число, если 1 ставлю та же ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: и если просто '' (нет ничего) тоже ошибка синтаксиса... бред, но это так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO league(user,email,password,rival,`key`) 
                    VALUES ('$this->user','$this->email','$this->pass','0','0')";
```

**key** и другие зарезервированные поля нужно брать в `